# How to change Compiler Option in Visual Studio 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, compiler-options

I tried to run my application and got this problem:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ComUtilitiesLib'

After googling around, I found a way to fix that issue by changing the compiler option.

However, I really don't know how to change the setting of compiler options (in the project properties) to explicitly produce an "x86" (i.e., 32-bit) app.

What I see then view the project's properties were just: " Application, Build, Build Events, Debug, ... etc". Just the Compile Options disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Build Menu -> Configuration Manager. On Active Solution Platform -> Select New or Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler options are part of the [Build page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It sounds like you want to modify the Platform value.

Comment: hi, thank for your help. Now I'm able to change the target platform to x86 CPU but the issue with "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.ComUtilitiesLib'" still persists. 
Do you have any idea how can I fix that issue!?

Comment: @MyticMoon: No, but I know nothing about that assembly. I was only answering the question asked...